# What to do with the output of ExternalProject_add? IMPORTED vs INTERFACE libraries

Tags: cmake

This is my topmost CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test LANGUAGES Fortran)
add_executable(main main.f90)
add_subdirectory(external)
target_link_libraries(main extlib)
```

Subdirectory "external" defines one external project, which produces some libraries and header files. What is the best practice of collecting the output of `ExternalProject_add` so that I could link that to the main executable? Currently, I'm using an INTERFACE library, like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_add(my-external
  SOURCE_DIR ext_source
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/configure
      --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  BUILD_COMMAND make)

add_library(extlib INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(extlib my-external)
target_include_directories(extlib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
foreach(_lib lib1 lib2 lib3)
  target_link_libraries(extlib INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/${_lib}.a)
endforeach()
```

Searching the web, it seems to me that people often use IMPORTED libraries instead for capturing the results of `ExternalProject_add`. However, you can only connect one IMPORTED library with one file produced by `ExternalProject_add` and any header directories would need to be separately propagated back to the parent directory so that `main` could use them. It seems to me than an INTERFACE library is better here because you can glob everything produced by the external project into a single target. In my actual project I have several external projects and ideally I would like to have one target per external project to keep things clean.

In general, **should I use IMPORTED or INTERFACE libraries when dealing with external libraries** and what would be the main benefits?

EDIT

Based on the dicussion below, I made an attempt using imported libraries only:

```
foreach(_lib lib1 lib2 lib3)
  add_library(${_lib} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
  add_dependencies(${_lib} my-external)
  set_target_properties(${_lib} PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/${_lib}.a)
endforeach()
set_target_properties(lib1 PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(lib1 INTERFACE lib2 lib3)
```

It takes about the same effort as with an interface library and I guess is ultimately a matter of style.

Comment: Smells as "**opinion-based**" question for me. You have already described main(?) difference between IMPORTED and INTERFACE libraries. For me, using IMPORTED library looks more "CMake way". Except from large library collections like Boost, I can hardly imaging someone *use* several libraries from a single ExternalProject at once. Usually you use functions from a single library, and other libraries are needed only for given one. Note, that you can also adjust link relations between *IMPORTED* targets.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know if this is opinion based or if I'm missing some important technical knowledge. It seems to me that imported and interface are not fundamentally different. Both create a sort of alias for targets not built by the project. By adjusting link relations do you mean something like `target_link_libraries(extlib INTERFACE <..>/lib.a)`?

Comment: Also, how do you include the header directories with an imported target? I tried setting the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property but I can get a `non-existent path` error when I try to link to the main executable.

Comment: As "link relations" I mean `target_link_libraries(extlib1 INTERFACE extlib2)` where both `extlib1` and `extlib2` are *IMPORTED* targets, each of which is bound to its own library file. (In you question post you are correct in that *IMPORTED* target corresponds to a single library file). Property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` should work for *IMPORTED* target.

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work with imported libraries (see edit). Turns out it's quite simple and straightforwad. Do I understand correctly that interface libraries are mainly intented to be used with header only libraries?

Comment: Yes, you "edit" code is what I have meant. `Do I understand correctly that interface libraries are mainly intented to be used with header only libraries?` As far as I know, *INTERFACE* libraries has been created for, among other things, header-only libraries. But I don't know whether header-only libraries is the *main purpose* of *INTERFACE* keyword. *INTERFACE* librasry could be a source library. Also, there are INTERFACE IMPORTED libraries, which are something above my imagination:)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the discussion!